# django-rest-framework: Can Ihave multiple templates per ViewSet?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-rest-viewsets

I've created a serializer and ViewSet for my model and added a template for a list view. To get to see the web page (template) the ordering render classes must be correct and one needs to add the `TemplateHTMLRenderer` to the list of renderers.

This now leads to the issue that when wanting to browse to a specific record like

```
/mymodel/5
```

in the browser, I get shown the list view too.

The goal is to have 1 url that serves the api (json) or the web page both for list and detail views.
(/mymodel = list, /mymodel/5 = detail)

The question is: how can I have multiple templates (list/detail) based on one ViewSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to override the get_template_names method and return the template according to the action being performed.

```
def get_template_names(self):
    if self.action == 'list':            
        return ['list.html']
    elif self.action == 'retrieve':            
        return ['details.html']
```